# Finding $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(ax)-\cos(bx)}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I am practicing calculus section of GRE Math Subject test, and I can't figure out a way to do the following integral:
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos (ax) - \cos (bx)}{x}dx.$$

I absolutely have no clue how to do this. Can someone show me the solution explicitly? Thank you.

Comment: Lookup [Frullani integral](https://www.maths.lancs.ac.uk/~jameson/frullani.pdf)

Comment: Although Frullani Integrals are the main idea here, I don't think this is a duplicate of the cited question since $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\cos(x)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 6):

Since $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\cos(x)$ does not exist, we can't simply apply [Frullani Integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral), but we can use the ideas behind them:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(ax)-\cos(bx)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\lim_{\substack{\epsilon\to0^+\\M\to+\infty}}\int_\epsilon^M\frac{\cos(ax)-\cos(bx)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\lim_{\substack{\epsilon\to0^+\\M\to+\infty}}\left[\int_{a\epsilon}^{aM}\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_{b\epsilon}^{bM}\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]\\
&=\lim_{\substack{\epsilon\to0^+\\M\to+\infty}}\left[\int_{a\epsilon}^{b\epsilon}\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_{aM}^{bM}\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]\\
&=\log(b/a)-\lim_{M\to+\infty}\int_{aM}^{bM}\frac1x\,\mathrm{d}\sin(x)\\
&=\log(b/a)-\lim_{M\to+\infty}\left[\frac{\sin(bM)}{bM}-\frac{\sin(aM)}{aM}+\int_{aM}^{bM}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]\\[6pt]
&=\log(b/a)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: (+1) Hi Rob.  This is similar to the development in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437537/int-eta-epsilon-fraccos-lambda-x-cos-mu-xxdx/1437559#1437559).

Comment: @MarkViola: indeed. This question is cleaner since the limit simplifies things.

Comment: @robjohn in the link I posted they cover that case.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos (ax)-\cos (bx)}x dx=\int_0^\infty dx\int_a^b\sin ux du
=\int_a^b du \int_0^\infty{\sin u x}\, dx =\int_a^b\frac { du}u=\ln\left|\frac ba\right|
$$

where
$$
\int_0^\infty{\sin u x}\, dx =\lim_{b\to0}\int_0^\infty{e^{-b x}\sin u x}\, dx=\lim_{b\to0}\frac u {b^2+u^2}=\frac1u
$$

Comment: My Fubini senses are tingling.

Comment: Why is this answer downvoted? If it is wrong, I will delete it. Did I make a mistake with Fubini?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but yes, there is a major concern with regards to Fubini. Your $\sin(ux)$ integral does not converge.

Comment: Wait a sec. Was your regularization on the bottom always there? If so, it didn't show for me originally. Must have been a browser hiccup!

Comment: The second line was always in the answer. I can apply Fubini as I show that $\int_0^\infty{\sin u x}\, dx$ converges.

Comment: Very nice.. I like the limit part.

Comment: Doesn't Fubini's theorem only apply when the integrals in question converge absolutely? $\int_0^\infty \sin(ux)dx$ does not converge absolutely, so I do not see how Fubini's theorem applies.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y\geqslant X\geqslant 0$, you have
$$ \int_{X}^{Y}{\frac{\cos(ax)-\cos(bx)}{x}dx}=\int_{aX}^{aY}{\frac{\cos(u)}{u}du}-\int_{bX}^{bY}{\frac{\cos(u)}{u}du} $$
Since $\cos$ is even we can suppose $a,b>0$. Hence letting $Y\rightarrow+\infty$ gives
$$ \int_{X}^{+\infty}{\frac{\cos(ax)-\cos(bx)}{x}dx}=\int_{aX}^{+\infty}{\frac{\cos(u)}{u}du}-\int_{bX}^{+\infty}{\frac{\cos(u)}{u}du}=\int_{aX}^{bX}{\frac{\cos(u)}{u}du}$$
Letting $X\rightarrow 0$ gives $$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}{\frac{\cos(ax)-\cos(bx)}{x}dx}=\ln\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$$

Comment: Letting the upper limits approach infinity and then subtracting then needs to be justified, especially when they do so at different rates.

Comment: The integrals $\int_0^{+\infty}{\frac{\cos(bx)-\cos(ax)}{x}dx}$ and $\int_0^{+\infty}{\frac{\cos(x)}{x}dx}$ converge.