# On $\int_0^{\pi} \operatorname{Si}^n(x) \ \mathrm{d}x $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

The Sine Integral, $\operatorname{Si}(x)$, is defined as $$\operatorname{Si}(x)=\int_0^x \frac{\sin t}{t} \ \mathrm{d}t $$

It follows that $$\int_0^{\pi} \operatorname{Si}(x) \ \mathrm{d}x = \bigg[x \operatorname{Si}(x) \bigg]_0^{\pi}-\int_0^{\pi} \sin x \ \mathrm{d}x = \pi \operatorname{Si} (\pi)-2$$ and further $$\int_0^{\pi} \operatorname{Si}^2 (x) \ \mathrm{d}x = \bigg[ x \operatorname{Si}^2(x) \bigg]_0^{\pi} -2\int_0^{\pi} \operatorname{Si} (x) \sin x \ \mathrm{d}x \\ = \pi \operatorname{Si}^2(\pi) -2 \left( \big[ -\cos x \operatorname{Si} (x) \big]_0^{\pi}+\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin x \cos x}{x} \ \mathrm{d}x \right)\\ = \pi \operatorname{Si}^2(\pi)-2 \operatorname{Si} (\pi)-\int_{2x=0}^{2\pi}\frac{\sin 2x}{2x} \ \mathrm{d}(2x)\\ = \pi\operatorname{Si}^2(\pi)-2 \operatorname{Si} (\pi)-\operatorname{Si} (2\pi)$$

Following a similar procedure on $\int_0^{\pi} \operatorname{Si}^3(x) \ \mathrm{d}x$ doesn’t quite work, because it requires evaluating the integral $\int_0^{\pi} \operatorname{Si}^2(x) \sin x \ \mathrm{d}x$, or equivalently, $\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\operatorname{Si}(x) \sin 2x}{x} \ \mathrm{d}x$.

This leads me to ask, can (and how can) $\int_0^{\pi} \operatorname{Si}^3(x) \ \mathrm{d}x$ be expressed in terms of elementary or special functions? How about the general case, i.e.  $$\color{purple}{\int_0^{\pi} \operatorname{Si}^n(x) \ \mathrm{d}x} \; ? $$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126498/discussion-on-question-by-tavish-on-int-0-pi-operatornamesinx-math).

Answer (score 8):

Here is an observation that seems to hint a *negative* answer to OP's question.

---

Considering that $\pi$ does not play a particular role in the special values for $\operatorname{Si}(\cdot)$, the question would be almost equivalent to investigating the antiderivatives of $\operatorname{Si}(x)^k$'s. Now let us write

$$F(x) = \int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{\sin t}{t} \, \mathrm{d}t = \frac{\pi}{2} - \operatorname{Si}(x)$$

for the complementary version of $\operatorname{Si}(\cdot)$. In light of the binomial theorem, it is clear that $\int\operatorname{Si}(x)^n\,\mathrm{d}x$ can be computed if all of $\int F(x)^k\,\mathrm{d}x$ for $k=0,\dots,n$ can be computed. So we will shift our focus to finding the antiderivatives of $F(x)^k$'s.

Now employing OP's technique, we find that

\begin{align*}
\int F(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
&= x F(x) + \int \sin x \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= x F(x) - \cos x + C
\end{align*}

and

\begin{align*}
\int F(x)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x
&= x F(x)^2 + 2\int F(x) \sin x \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= x F(x)^2 - 2F(x)\cos x - \int \frac{2\sin x\cos x}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= x F(x)^2 - 2F(x)\cos x + F(2x) + C.
\end{align*}

These computations, together with the asymptotic formula for $F(x)$, reveal the closed-forms for the following integrals:

$$ I_1 = \int_{0}^{\infty} F(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 1 \qquad\text{and}\qquad I_2 = \int_{0}^{\infty} F(x)^2 \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2}. $$

Similarly, if $\int F(x)^3 \, \mathrm{d}x$ admits a closed-form expression involving $F(\cdot)$, then we can expect that the integral

$$ I_3 = \int_{0}^{\infty} F(x)^3 \, \mathrm{d}x $$

will admit an elementary closed-form (or at least assume a simpler formula than $\int_{0}^{\pi}\operatorname{Si}(x)^3\,\mathrm{d}x$). However, we can prove that

$$I_3 = \frac{\pi^2}{4} - \frac{3}{2}\log^2 2 - \frac{3}{4}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) = 1.545982100082988\dots $$

holds, where $\operatorname{Li}_2(\cdot)$ is the [dilogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm). Since this expression seems non-elementary, I am skeptical about the ideal that $\operatorname{Si}(x)^3$ has an elementary antiderivative.

---

*Addendum: Proof of the formula for $I_3$.* We find that

\begin{align*}
\int F(x)^3 \, \mathrm{d}x
&= x F(x)^3 + 3\int F(x)^2 \sin x \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= x F(x)^3 - 3F(x)^2\cos x - 6\int \frac{F(x)\sin x\cos x}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= x F(x)^3 - 3F(x)^2\cos x - 3\int \frac{F(x)\sin(2x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x.
\end{align*}

From this, we get

$$ I_3 = \frac{3\pi^2}{4} - 3\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{F(x)\sin(2x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

To compute this, we adopt the Feynman's trick. More precisely, we consider the parametrized integral

$$ I_3(s) = \frac{3\pi^2}{4} - 3\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{F(x)\sin(sx)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x. $$

Then

\begin{align*}
I_3'(s)
&= -3\int_{0}^{\infty} F(x)\cos(sx) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= -\frac{3}{s}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x \sin(sx)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= -\frac{3}{2s}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos((s-1)x) - \cos((1+s)x)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

The last integral can be computed using the [Frullani's integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3358742/finding-int-0-infty-frac-cosax-cosbxxdx), yielding

\begin{align*}
I_3'(s)
&= -3\int_{0}^{\infty} F(x)\cos(sx) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= -\frac{3}{s}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\sin x \sin(sx)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \frac{3}{2s}(\log\left|s-1\right| - \log(s+1)).
\end{align*}

So it follows that

\begin{align*}
I_3 = I_3(2)
&= I_3(0) + \int_{0}^{2} I_3'(s) \, \mathrm{d}s \\
&= \frac{3\pi^2}{4}+ \int_{0}^{2} \frac{3}{2s}(\log\left|s-1\right| - \log(s+1)) \, \mathrm{d}s.
\end{align*}

By computing the last integral using the dilogarithm, we can complete the proof of the formula.

Answer (score 8):

This note is divided into

- Part I: an elaboration of my comments (which have now been moved to chat), and
- Part II: in agreement with Sangchul's claim that an elementary closed form does not exist.

**Part I:** Writing the expression as a double integral, we have \begin{align}\int_0^\pi\frac{\operatorname{Si}(x)\sin2x}x\,dx&=\int_0^\pi\int_0^1\frac{\sin yx\sin2x}{yx}\,dy\,dx\\&=\frac12\int_0^1\int_0^\pi\frac{\cos((y-2)x)-\cos((y+2)x)}{yx}\,dx\,dy\\&=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Ci}((y-2)\pi)-\log(y-2)-(\operatorname{Ci}((y+2)\pi)-\log(y+2))}y\,dy.\end{align} This follows from the series expansion $$\operatorname{Ci}(x)=\gamma+\log x+\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{2n(2n)!}\tag1$$ so that \begin{align}\lim_{x\to0}[\operatorname{Ci}((y+2)x)-\operatorname{Ci}((y-2)x)]&=\lim_{x\to0}\left[\log((y+2)x)-\log((y-2)x)+\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{f(n,y)x^{2n}}{2n(2n)!}\right]\\&=\log(y+2)-\log(y-2)\end{align} where \begin{align}f(n,y)&=(-1)^n((y+2)^{2n}-(y-2)^{2n})\\&=(-1)^n\sum_{0\le k\le2n}\binom{2n}ky^{2n-k}2^k(1-(-1)^k)\\&=(-1)^n\sum_{1\le k\le n}\binom{2n}{2k-1}y^{2n-2k+1}2^{2k}.\end{align} Using $(1)$ again, we obtain \begin{align}\int_0^\pi\frac{\operatorname{Si}(x)\sin2x}x\,dx&=-\frac12\int_0^1\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-1)^n\pi^{2n}f(n,y)}{2n(2n)!y}\,dy\\&=-\frac14\sum_{n\ge1}\sum_{1\le k\le n}\int_0^1\frac{(-1)^n\pi^{2n}4^k}{n(2k-1)!(2n-2k+1)!}y^{2n-2k}\,dy\\&=-\frac14\sum_{n\ge1}\sum_{1\le k\le n}\frac{(-1)^n\pi^{2n}4^k}{n(2n-2k+1)(2k-1)!(2n-2k+1)!}\end{align} where the sum-integral interchange is justified by Fubini. This can be rewritten in one summation as $$\int_0^\pi\frac{\operatorname{Si}(x)\sin2x}x\,dx=-2\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-1)^n\pi^{2n}}{(2n)!(2n-1)}{}_3F_2\left(\frac12-n,\frac12-n,1-n;\frac32,\frac32-n;4\right)$$ by expressing the denominator in terms of Pochhammer symbols. [Here is verification](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uyqtdjjcun).

**Part 2:** It is important to note that the upper limit of $\pi$ does not simplify the integral, as mentioned in Sangchul's answer. From Part I, we have \begin{align}\int_0^\pi\frac{\operatorname{Si}(x)\sin2x}x\,dx=\lim_{\epsilon\to0^+}\int_\epsilon^1\frac{\operatorname{Ci}((y-2)\pi)-\log(y-2)-(\operatorname{Ci}((y+2)\pi)-\log(y+2))}{2y}\,dy.\end{align} The antiderivatives of $\log(y\pm2)/y$ can be readily expressed in terms of dilogarithms, so the only issue stems from the evaluation of $$\int_\epsilon^1\frac{\operatorname{Ci}((y\pm2)\pi)}y\,dy=\int_{(\epsilon\pm2)\pi}^{(1\pm2)\pi}\frac{\operatorname{Ci}(w)}{w\mp2\pi}\,dw.$$ This is why I strongly doubt there is an elementary closed form for $\int_0^\pi\operatorname{Si}^3(x)\,dx$, as $\operatorname{Ci}$ is non-periodic and the limits do not allow for any simplifications to be made.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure my result is entirely correct or not but if there is any mistakes then please tell me in the comments.

So the integral is, $\textstyle\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{\pi}\operatorname{Si}^n(x)dx}$

I think we can start to simplify this using integration by parts, more specifically the DI method
(If you don't know what DI method is then for introduction you can watch [this](https://youtu.be/2I-_SV8cwsw) and [this](https://youtu.be/8xPfNuXLSwk) video.

---

So let's start-

$\begin{array}
\ & \text{D} & \text{I}\\
+ & \operatorname{Si}^n(x) & 1\\
- & n\operatorname{Si}^{n-1}(x)\frac{\sin(x)}{x} & x
\end{array}$

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\therefore\int_{0}^{\pi}\operatorname{Si}^n(x)dx}$

$\textstyle\displaystyle{=x\operatorname{Si}^n(x)\bigg]_{0}^{\pi}-n\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x)\operatorname{Si}^{n-1}(x)dx}$

$\textstyle\displaystyle{=\pi\operatorname{Si}^n(\pi)-n\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x)\operatorname{Si}^{n-1}(x)dx}$

---

Let's do this process again to find some pattern.

$\begin{array}
\ & \text{D} & \text{I}\\
+ & \sin(x)\operatorname{Si}^{n-1}(x) & 1\\
- & \begin{align}\cos(x)\operatorname{Si}^{n-1}(x) & +(n-1)\operatorname{Si}^{n-2}(x)\frac{\sin^2(x)}{x}\end{align} & x
\end{array}$

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\therefore\int_{0}^{\pi}\operatorname{Si}^n(x)dx}$

$\textstyle\displaystyle{=\pi\operatorname{Si}^n(\pi)-nx\operatorname{Si}^{n-1}(x)\sin(x)\bigg]_{0}^{\pi}+n\int_{0}^{\pi}x\cos(x)\operatorname{Si}^{n-1}(x)dx+n(n-1)\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^2(x)\operatorname{Si}^{n-2}(x)dx}$

Here, $\textstyle\displaystyle{nx\operatorname{Si}^{n-1}(x)\sin(x)\bigg]_{0}^{\pi}=0}$

---

And let's do it for the last time

$\begin{array}
\ & \text{D} &\text{I}\\
+ & \sin^2(x)\operatorname{Si}^{n-2}(x) & 1\\
- & \begin{align}2\cos(x)\operatorname{Si}^{n-2}(x) & +(n-2)\operatorname{Si}^{n-3}(x)\frac{\sin^3(x)}{x}\end{align} & x
\end{array}$

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\therefore\int_{0}^{\pi}\operatorname{Si}^n(x)}$

$\textstyle\displaystyle{=\pi\operatorname{Si}^n(\pi)
+n\int_{0}^{\pi}x\cos(x)\operatorname{Si}^{n-1}(x)dx+n(n-1)x\sin^2(x)\operatorname{Si}^{n-2}(x)\bigg]_{0}^{\pi}-2n(n-1)\int_{0}^{\pi}x\cos(x)\operatorname{Si}^{n-2}(x)dx+n(n-1)(n-2)\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^3(x)\operatorname{Si}^{n-3}(x)dx}$

Here, $\textstyle\displaystyle{n(n-1)x\sin^2(x)\operatorname{Si}^{n-2}(x)\bigg]_{0}^{\pi}=0}$

---

So now let's find patterns, at each step:-

$\pi\operatorname{Si}^n(\pi)$ stays, the term which is in the form
$\textstyle\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^k(x)\operatorname{Si}^{n-k}(x)dx}$ is broken into

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x\sin^k(x)\operatorname{Si}^{n-k}(x)\bigg]_{0}^{\pi}}$,

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\frac{kn!}{(n-k)!}\int_{0}^{\pi}x\cos(x)\operatorname{Si}^{n-k}(x)dx}$ and

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\frac{n!}{[n-(k+1)]!}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{k+1}(x)\operatorname{Si}^{n-(k+1)}(x)dx}$ where

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x\sin^k(x)\operatorname{Si}^{n-k}(x)\bigg]_{0}^{\pi}}$ vanishes to $0$,

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\frac{n!k}{(n-k)!}\int_{0}^{\pi}x\cos(x)\operatorname{Si}^{n-k}(x)dx}$ stays and

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\frac{n!}{[n-(k+1)]!}\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^{k+1}(x)\operatorname{Si}^{n-(k+1)}(x)dx}$ is broken down further.

---

So finally we get,

$\textstyle\displaystyle{\int_{0}^{\pi}\operatorname{Si}^n(x)dx}$

$\textstyle\displaystyle{=\pi\operatorname{Si}^n(\pi)$
 $+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n!k}{(n-k)!}\int_{0}^{\pi}x\cos(x)\operatorname{Si}^{n-k}(x)dx}$

This is as far as I have come. If I can work out more then I would edit my answer to add that.

Comment: You're the first person I've seen on MSE to use the DI method explicitly, nice :)

Comment: @A-Level-Student. Thanks. I hate the u-dv method.

Answer (score 3):

As it was mentioned in the OP,
\begin{align}
&I=\int\limits_0^\pi \operatorname{Si}^3(x)\,\text dx 
\;\overset{\text{IBP}}{=\!=}\;\operatorname{Si}^3(x) x\bigg|_0^\pi
-3\int\limits_0^\pi x\operatorname{Si}^2(x)\operatorname{sinc}(x)\,\text dx
=\pi\operatorname{Si}^3(\pi)
+3\int\limits_0^\pi \operatorname{Si}^2(x)\,\text d\cos x\\[4pt]
&\overset{\text{IBP}}{=\!=}\;\pi\operatorname{Si}^3(\pi)+3\operatorname{Si}^2(x)\cos x \bigg|_0^\pi - 6\int\limits_0^\pi \cos x\operatorname{Si}(x)\operatorname{sinc}(x)\,\text dx
=\pi\operatorname{Si}^3(\pi)-3\operatorname{Si}^2(\pi)-6I_1,
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
&I_1=\int\limits_0^\pi \operatorname{Si}(x)\operatorname{sinc}(2x)\,\text dx
=\int\limits_0^\pi \int\limits_0^x\operatorname{sinc}(y)\operatorname{sinc}(2x)\,\text dy\,\text dx
=\int\limits_0^\pi \int\limits_y^\pi\operatorname{sinc}(y)\operatorname{sinc}(2x)\,\text dx\,\text dy\\[4pt]
&=\dfrac12\int\limits_0^\pi \int\limits_y^\pi\operatorname{sinc}(y)\operatorname{sinc}(2x)\,\text d(2x)\,\text dy
=\dfrac12\int\limits_0^\pi \operatorname{sinc}(y)\operatorname{Si}(2x)\bigg|_y^\pi\,\text dy\\[4pt]
&=\dfrac12\int\limits_0^\pi \operatorname{sinc}(y)(\operatorname{Si}(2\pi)-\operatorname{Si}(2y))\,\text dy,
\end{align}
$$I_1=\dfrac12\operatorname{Si}(\pi)\operatorname{Si}(2\pi)-\dfrac12\int\limits_0^\pi \operatorname{sinc}(x)\operatorname{Si}(2x)\,\text dx.\tag1$$
Applying the known series in the form of
$$\operatorname{Si}(2x)=\pi\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty J^2_{\large k+^1/_2}(x) \tag2,$$
where
$$J_{\large^1/_2}(x)=\sqrt{\dfrac2{\pi x}}\sin x,\quad J_{\large^3/_2}(x) =\sqrt{\dfrac2{\pi x}}(\operatorname{sinc} x-\cos x),\tag3$$
$$J_{\large m+^3/_2}(x) = \dfrac{2m+1}x J_{\large m+^1/_2}(x)-J_{\large m-^1/_2}(x),\quad m=1, 2\dots,\tag4$$
allows to get high accuracy closed-form approximations.

For example, from the equality
$$ \begin{align}
&S_{10}=\int\limits_0^\pi\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^9 J^2_{\large k+^1/_2}(x)\right)\operatorname{sinc} x \,\text dx =
\dfrac1{28605549772800 \pi^{17}}\\[4pt]
&\times\bigg(198641616776068257792000000 - 51388022909702134656000000 \pi^2\\[4pt] &+ 4492572854595378448896000 \pi^4 - 155376628399064274048000 \pi^6\\[4pt]
&+ 2259641487353598835200 \pi^8 - 12461916450169368000 \pi^{10}\\[4pt]
&+ 24885770867920800 \pi^{12} + 186094688685480 \pi^{14}\\[4pt]
&+ \pi^{16} (-64011445084 + 112455910172835(\operatorname{Ci}(\pi) - \operatorname{Ci}(3\pi)+\ln3))\bigg)\\[4pt]
&\approx 0.76480\,65196\,02706\,51930\,94484
\end{align} $$
should
$$I\approx \pi \operatorname{Si}^3(\pi)-3\operatorname{Si^2}(\pi)
-3\operatorname{Si}(\pi)\operatorname{Si}(2\pi)+3\pi S_{10},$$
$$I\approx 8.99407\,09143\,86010\,29167.$$
Numeric integration gives
$$I\approx 8.99407\,09143\,90144\,50150.$$

However, the closed form of *I* was not obtained.

Comment: The Mathjax isn’t rendering at the end. Can you fix it?

Comment: @Tavish I don't see this, but updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative series expression for the integral

$$i = \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin(2x)}{x} \text{Si}(x )\,dx\tag{1}$$

which I obtained from replacing the $\sin$ by its power series and integrating termwise. A similar series was provided by [TheSimpliFire](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4175632/198592.).

From

$$c(n) = \int_0^{\pi } x^{2 n} \text{Si}(x) \, dx \\
= \frac{\pi ^{2 n+1} \left(2 (n+1) \text{Si}(\pi )-\pi  \, _1F_2\left(n+1;\frac{3}{2},n+2;-\frac{\pi ^2}{4}\right)\right)}{2 (n+1) (2 n+1)}\tag{2}$$

which I have derived by looking for a recursive solution for $c(n)$ (or alternatively simply emloying Mathematica), I get

$$i = s := s_1 + s_2$$

where

$$s_1 =\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n (2 \pi )^{2 n+1} \text{Si}(\pi )}{(2 n+1) (2 n+1)!} =\text{Si}(\pi ) \text{Si}(2 \pi ) \tag{3}$$

and

$$s_2 =-\pi\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n (2 \pi )^{2 n+1} \, _1F_2\left(n+1;\frac{3}{2},n+2;-\frac{\pi ^2}{4}\right)}{2 (n+1) (2 n+1) (2 n+1)!}\tag{4}$$

The hypergeometric function $s_2$ is related to Bessel functions as can be seen from the first four summands

$$\begin{align}\left\{-4,\frac{1}{9} (-2) \left(4+\sqrt{2} \pi ^3 J_{-\frac{1}{2}}(\pi )+2 \sqrt{2} \pi ^2 J_{-\frac{3}{2}}(\pi )\right),\frac{1}{75} (-2) \left(48-\sqrt{2} \pi ^4 J_{-\frac{3}{2}}(\pi )+\sqrt{2} \pi ^5 J_{-\frac{5}{2}}(\pi )-8 \sqrt{2} \pi ^3 J_{-\frac{5}{2}}(\pi )\right),\frac{4 \left(-1440+\sqrt{2} \pi ^5 \left(\pi ^2-9\right) J_{-\frac{5}{2}}(\pi )+3 \sqrt{2} \pi ^4 \left(\pi ^2-16\right) J_{-\frac{7}{2}}(\pi )\right)}{2205}\right\}\end{align}\tag{4a}$$

They simplify, however, to these curious polynomials in $\pi$:

$$\begin{align}\left\{-4,\frac{4 \pi ^2}{9}-\frac{16}{9},-\frac{64}{25}+\frac{16 \pi ^2}{25}-\frac{4 \pi ^4}{75},\\
-\frac{256}{49}+\frac{64 \pi ^2}{49}-\frac{16 \pi ^4}{147}+\frac{8 \pi ^6}{2205}\right\}\end{align}\tag{4b}$$

(As expected) I was not able to calculate $s_2$ analytically.

But notice that the hypergeometric function appearing here is of smaller degree than that in the sum in [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4175632/198592.) so that maybe some progress is possible.

**EDIT**

The sum can also be written with a hypergeometric function with smaller parameters as

$$\begin{align}s=\left(\text{Si}(\pi )-\frac{1}{\pi }\right) \text{Si}(2 \pi )-\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n \left(2 (2 \pi )^{2 n}\right) \, _1F_2\left(n;\frac{1}{2},n+1;-\frac{\pi ^2}{4}\right)}{(2 n+1) (2 n+1)!}\end{align}\tag{5}$$

$\, _1F_2$ admits the representations

$$\begin{align}& \, _1F_2\left(n;\frac{1}{2},n+1;-\frac{\pi ^2}{4}\right)\\
& = n \sqrt{\pi }  \sum _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{1}{ (k+n) \Gamma \left(k+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\frac{z^k}{k!}|_{z\to -(\frac{\pi}{2})^2}\\
& =n \int_{0}^{1} x^{n-1}\cos(\pi \sqrt{x})\,dx=2 n \int_0^1  y^{2 n-1} \cos (\pi  y) \, dy\end{align}\tag{6}$$