# Is this a valid way to compute $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\alpha x)-\cos(\beta x)}{x}\text{d}x$?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, laplace-transform, gre-exam

I am not sure if the following way is valid to evaluate

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\alpha x)-\cos(\beta x)}{x}\text{d}x$$

[SOURCE](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emin/GRE/files/week1.pdf)

I saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3358742/finding-int-0-infty-frac-cosax-cosbxxdx) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61828/proof-of-frullanis-theorem)

But I am asking if the following is valid or not?

[image]

---

***Edit:***

Note that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(t)}{t}\text{d}t=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}\text{\{}f(t)\text{\}}\text{d}s$

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\alpha x)}{x}\text{d}x=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}\text{\{}\cos(\alpha x)\text{\}}\text{d}s=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{s}{s^2+\alpha^2}\text{d}s=\frac{1}{2}\log(s^2+\alpha^2)$, and

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(\beta x)}{x}\text{d}x=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}\text{\{}\cos(\beta x)\text{\}}\text{d}s=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{s}{s^2+\beta^2}\text{d}s=\frac{1}{2}\log(s^2+\beta^2)$

Taking the difference, we get:

$\frac{1}{2}\log(\frac{s^2+\alpha^2}{s^2+\beta^2})$

Now applying the limits $s=0$ to $s \rightarrow \infty$, we get:

$\frac{1}{2}\log(1)-\frac{1}{2}\log(\frac{\alpha^2}{\beta^2})=\log(\frac{\beta}{\alpha})$

---

Having the right answer does not mean that the way is right.

---

Your help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/42969)  Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @MartinR well, I will edit it now. Thanks for letting me know that pictures may not be legible.

Comment: No, it is not valid to compute a convergent integral by writing as the difference of two divergent integrals.

Comment: @GEdgar but for some limit problems, we have (sometimes) $\infty - \infty$ and that approach a finite value, sometime. So why in this case it is not valid? Thanks.

Comment: It's _nearly_ valid. One can easily write$$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(\alpha x)-\cos(\beta x)}{x}\mathrm{d}x&=\int_0^\infty\mathcal{L}\{\cos(\alpha t)-\cos(\beta t)\}\mathrm{d}s\\&=\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{s}{s^2+\alpha^2}-\frac{s}{s^2+\beta^2}\right)\mathrm{d}s\\&=\left[\frac12\ln\frac{s^2+\alpha^2}{s^2+\beta^2}\right]_0^\infty\\&=\ln\frac{\beta}{\alpha}.\end{align}$$

Comment: Is $$\int_0^\infty\frac{f(t)}{t}\;dt= \int_0^\infty\mathcal L\{f(t)\}\;ds$$valid for conditionally convergent improper integrals like this one?  Reference?

Comment: No, it is not valid. The function $\cos{(\alpha x)}/x$ has a pole at $x =0$, so integrating from $0$ to $\infty$ results in divergence. Same with the other integral.

Comment: @J.G. So the my idea of using Laplace transform is valid, except I should not split the integrand. Am I right?